# Hyperledger getParticipants

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

```
    function Exchange(exchange){
  // We do the actual exchange here:
  // We first need to get both actual nodes:
  var nodeIdFrom=exchange.nodeIdFrom;
  var quantity =exchange.quantity;
  var price = exchange.price;
  var nodeIdTo  =exchange.nodeIdTo;
  return getParticipantRegistry('org.acme.mynetwork.Node')
    .then(function(ParticipantRegistry){
    ParticipantRegistry.get(nodeIdFrom)
      .then(function(Participant){
        Participant.Need=Participant.Need+quantity;
        Participant.Balance_account=Participant.Balance_account+quantity*price;
      return ParticipantRegistry.update(Participant);
    });
  });
```

I'm trying to execute a transaction defined as:

```
transaction Exchange{
  o String nodeIdFrom
  o String nodeIdTo
  o Double quantity
  o Double Price
}
```

To execute a transaction (we take money somewhere and put it somewhere else). With only the ids of the nodes as a parameter.

But right now that function does not work, you can execute it on the playground but my node is not modified.
Is it possible to apply a transaction without giving node as Node (node is a Participant).

Answer (score 0):

it should work - here's an example (Using a fictitious sample 'Trader' Network and like you, I have defined 'qty' as a 'Double' in the Transaction model definition itself)  of updating an Asset by a specific identifier (you're doing something similar - Participant by ID) and then - updating the asset's quantity using the Promises chain below.  Suggest to use console.log() for outputs too when debugging.

So - given Transaction model:

```
transaction TraderById {
  o String tradeId
  o String tradingSymbol
  o Double qty
}
```

and an Asset modeled as:

```
asset Commodity identified by tradingSymbol {
    o String tradingSymbol
    o String description
    o String mainExchange
    o Double quantity
    --> Trader owner
}
```

you can update the Asset quantity ('quantity') as follows:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {org.acme.trading.TraderById} tradeById - the trade to be processed
 * @transaction
 */
function TradeById(tradeById){
    var commodityRegistry;
    return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.trading.Commodity')
    .then(function(registry){
        commodityRegistry=registry;
        return commodityRegistry.get(tradeById.tradingSymbol);
    })
    .then(function(result){
        result.quantity-=tradeById.qty;
        return commodityRegistry.update(result);
    });

}
```